# Is it possible to install only master when installing kubernetes with Kubespray?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubespray

I am trying to install kubernetes using kubespray.

I have successfully configured master and worker, but I wanted to know if only masters without workers could be installed. In `inventory.ini`, only the hostname of the master was specified and the installation proceeded, and the following failure message was displayed.

Is there a way to install only master excluding worker with kubespray?
help!

```
    failed: [node1] (item=kube-node) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "groups.get('kube-node')",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": "kube-node",
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
```

Comment: A k8s cluster with only a master, does not make too much sense. You can install the worker on the same machine as the master, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the `ignore_assert_errors=yes` option, I know this may sound like a workaround, but it seems to work as expected.
I'm not sure if installing just single master node is covered somewhere in the [kubespray documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

---

I will create a simple example to illustrate how it works.

Suppose I have one instance and I want it to be the Kubernetes master node:

```
# ifconfig ens4
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.186.15.206  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.186.15.206
```

First, I've prepared the inventory file:

```
# cat inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml 
all:
  hosts:
    node1:
      ansible_host: 10.186.15.206
      ip: 10.186.15.206
      access_ip: 10.186.15.206
  children:
    kube_control_plane:
      hosts:
        node1:
    kube-node:
      hosts: {}
    etcd:
      hosts:
        node1:
    k8s-cluster:
      children:
        kube_control_plane:
        kube-node:
    calico-rr:
      hosts: {}
```

Then I've deployed Kubespray with Ansible Playbook:
**NOTE:** I've used `-e ignore_assert_errors=yes` option.

```
# ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml  --become --become-user=root cluster.yml -e ignore_assert_errors=yes
...
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node1                      : ok=555  changed=121  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1128 rescued=0    ignored=2
```

After successful installation we can check if `node1` is really the master node:

```
# kubectl get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
node1   Ready    control-plane,master   4m30s   v1.20.6

# kubectl describe nodes node1 | grep -i taint
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

As you can see, node `node1` has a `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` taint indicating that it's indeed the master node.